# CSS border duplicates in IE 11 for a modal

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

This happens only in IE 11, i have a table in modal.

changing the height of the border does not change anything.

here's the html:

```html
<div class="modalDiv" id="modalDiv" style="left: 587px; top: 213px; width: 450px; height: 530px; display: block; opacity: 1;">
<table class="modalTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td>
            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td class="modalWindowHeader" onmousedown="dragStart(event)">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="modalWindowHeaderClose" onclick="closeModalWindow()"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="modalWindowContent">
            <iframe class="modalInnerIframe" id="modalIFrame" src="url" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" style="height: 100%; visibility: visible;"></iframe>
        </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td class="modalWindowBottomBar">
            <table width="100%" height="10" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td><img src="gif"></td>
                    <td width="5" class="modaldWindowBottomBarSlider" onmousedown="resizeStart(event)">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>               
            </tbody></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

here's the css of the border

```css
td.modalWindowBottomBar {
    background-image: url("gif");
    background-color:silver;    
    height:10px;
    text-align:right;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you create a `jsFiddle` to show us the problem?

Comment: I've put your code in a `jsFiddle`: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/nq68octt/ You can now add the rest of the relevant code.

Comment: @MelanciaUK updated the jsfiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/kumar239/nq68octt/3/

Comment: I still can't see what's the issue here.

Comment: @JonathanSampson 'background-repeat: repeat-x' leads to http://imgur.com/DFnn497

Comment: @MelanciaUK its in IE 11 only

Comment: I checked on `IE 11`, `Chrome` and `Firefox`, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is based on additional information presented in the comments, as well as access to the site in question. These details, and site-access, may not be present in the future.*

You have come across a layout bug in Internet Explorer it would seem. By setting the `<tbody>` element's height to `99%`, Internet Explorer proceeds to ignore the explicit heights applied to other elements, thus causing cells to become enlarged, and therefore show repeated backgrounds.

I've boiled your markup and styles down to the following:

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>a</td></tr>
        <tr><td>b</td></tr> 
        <tr><td>c</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```css
table, td {
    background: #7777FF;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table { height: 200px; }
tbody { height: 99%;   }
td    { padding: 10px; }

tr:first-child td, 
tr:last-child  td { 
    height: 10px;
}
```

When you view the above ([visit fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g0o0v369/1/)) in Chrome and Internet Explorer, you'll see a table that resembles the following. The left example (green) is Chrome, and the right example (blue) is Internet Explorer.

[image]

In both browsers the `<tbody>` has a height of `99%`. Upon hovering the blue table we reset the `height` to `auto`, which repairs the layout. This is the solution to your problem as well - simply remove the instruction to set height to `99%` and this should resolve the issue for you. *Alternatively, you could [set your heights on the table-rows](http://jsfiddle.net/g0o0v369/2/) instead.*

On my end I will file an interop bug on this and speak with the team regarding a solution in future versions of Internet Explorer. Ideally you shouldn't run into issues like this, so I'll do my best to ensure we behave like other browsers in situations like this.